# In C++98 'dvd1' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'

Tags: c++, c++98

How do I initialize dvd1?

`C:\Users\SuperUser\Google Drive>g++ -o a Question1.cpp`

> Question1.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>
> Question1.cpp:39:76: error: in C++98 'dvd1' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'
>
> dvd dvd1 = {"Zombie","BBC","James","English","Alw",2012,20170601,20170630};

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class dvd
{
    string movieName,movieProdComp,movieLeadActor,movieLanguage,renterName;
    int releaseYear,rentDate,returnDate;
    public:
        
        dvd(string mn,string mpc,string mla,string ml, string rn,int ry,int rd,int retd);
        void print();
};

dvd::dvd(string mn,string mpc,string mla,string ml, string rn, int ry,int rd,int retd){
    movieName=mn;
    movieProdComp=mpc;
    movieLeadActor=mla;
    movieLanguage=ml;
    renterName=rn;
    releaseYear=ry;
    rentDate=rd;
    returnDate=retd;
}

void dvd::print(){
    cout<<"Movie:"<<movieName<<endl;
    cout<<"Production:"<<movieProdComp<<endl;
    cout<<"Starring:"<<movieLeadActor<<endl;
    cout<<"Language:"<<movieLanguage<<endl;
    cout<<"Rented By:"<<renterName<<endl;
    cout<<"Released:"<<releaseYear<<endl;
    cout<<"Rent Date:"<<rentDate<<endl;
    cout<<"Return Date:"<<returnDate<<endl;
}

int main(){
    dvd();
    dvd dvd1 = {"Zombie","BBC","James","English","Alw",2012,20170601,20170630};
    dvd1.print();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), and for non-aggregate types it's only supported in C++11:

```
dvd dvd1 = {"Zombie","BBC","James","English","Alw",2012,20170601,20170630};
```

For C++98, you might want to change it a little, to call constructor as usual:

```
dvd dvd1("Zombie","BBC","James","English","Alw",2012,20170601,20170630);
```

Comment: Nit:  It is only supported *for classes with an explicit constructor* in C++11.  C++98 is find with `struct simple { int i, j; } value = { 0, 1 };`

Comment: @MartinBonner thanks, I added a note about proper constructors. Regarding struct initialization, my *personal opinion* is to omit such notice. C++ *wants* structs to be classes, so let's not talk about the moments when it *fails* :)

Comment: I think your edit makes the answer worse.  Note that C++98 is equally happy with `class simple { public: int i, j; } value = { 0, 1 };`.  Trying to pretend that list initialization doesn't work unless you have a proper constructor is just silly.

Comment: @MartinBonner rolled back. At this point, I'm confused. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list says that brace-init is only supported starting with `c++11`, while I clearly see that GCC with `-std=c++98` compiles your example without even a warning. How so?

Comment: @iehrlich I believe cppreference means list initialization for purposes other than aggregate initialization is supported post C++11. Aggregate initialization has always been legal, it is how you initialize structs in C

Comment: Invoking a constructor via a brace init list is C++11.  Initializing an *aggregate* (see §8.5.1 in [n4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) for definition of *aggregate*) was inherited from C, and has always been valid.

Answer (score 5):

`dvd` is a non-[aggregate type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), which can't be initialized with braced intializer until C++11, which supports [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization). (More precisely what you're trying to do is copy-list-initialization.)

For C++98 you can write

```
dvd dvd1 ("Zombie","BBC","James","English","Alw",2012,20170601,20170630);
dvd dvd1 = dvd("Zombie","BBC","James","English","Alw",2012,20170601,20170630);
```

In C++98 you can use [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) like `dvd dvd1 = {...};` only when it's an aggregate type; for this case `dvd` has a user-defined constructor then makes it not.